How to make top labels aligned with the columns of a probability tree?
I am trying to make the chart below in Latex:
My code is as follows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[landscape, top=1cm, bottom=1cm, left=1cm, right=1cm]{geometry} % Adjust margins
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}

% First TikZ environment for the labels (moved down by 1 cm)
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Place the labels at a lower position
    \node[anchor=west] at (2, 5) {\textbf{Events}};  % Moved from y=9 to y=8
    \node[anchor=west] at (7, 5) {\textbf{Customers using credit card, x}};
    \node[anchor=west] at (16, 5) {\textbf{Probabilities}};
\end{tikzpicture}

% Add some vertical space between labels and the tree
\vspace*{3cm} % You can adjust this to move the tree further down

% Second TikZ environment for the tree (start it further down)
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  grow=east, % Tree grows to the right
  level 1/.style={level distance=40mm, sibling distance=80mm}, % Sibling distance for separation
  level 2/.style={level distance=40mm, sibling distance=40mm},
  level 3/.style={level distance=40mm, sibling distance=20mm},
  edge from parent/.style={draw, ->, thick}, % Standard arrow style
  every node/.style={fill=white, rounded corners, font=\footnotesize}
  ]

  % Root node (start tree here)
  \node at (0, 6) {Start} % Tree positioned at y=6
    % First level (Customer 1: S and F)
    child {
        node {S} % First node for S
        % Second level (Customer 2: S and F, separate routes)
        child {
            node {S}
            % Third level (Customer 3: S and F, separate routes)
            child { node (SSS) {S} edge from parent node[above] {0.85} }
            child { node (SSF) {F} edge from parent node[below] {0.15} }
            edge from parent node[above] {0.85}
        }
        child {
            node {F}
            % Third level (Customer 3: S and F, separate routes)
            child { node (SFS) {S} edge from parent node[above] {0.85} }
            child { node (SFF) {F} edge from parent node[below] {0.15} }
            edge from parent node[below] {0.15}
        }
        edge from parent node[above] {0.85}
    }
    child {
        node {F} % First node for F
        % Second level (Customer 2: S and F, separate routes)
        child {
            node {S}
            % Third level (Customer 3: S and F, separate routes)
            child { node (FSS) {S} edge from parent node[above] {0.85} }
            child { node (FSF) {F} edge from parent node[below] {0.15} }
            edge from parent node[above] {0.85}
        }
        child {
            node {F}
            % Third level (Customer 3: S and F, separate routes)
            child { node (FFS) {S} edge from parent node[above] {0.85} }
            child { node (FFF) {F} edge from parent node[below] {0.15} }
            edge from parent node[below] {0.15}
        }
        edge from parent node[below] {0.15}
    };

    % Labeling Events, Customers using credit card, and Probabilities aligned with the end of the branches
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (SSS.east) {SSS \hspace{10mm} 3 \hspace{10mm} 0.6141};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (SSF.east) {SSF \hspace{10mm} 2 \hspace{10mm} 0.1084};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (SFS.east) {SFS \hspace{10mm} 2 \hspace{10mm} 0.1084};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (SFF.east) {SFF \hspace{10mm} 1 \hspace{10mm} 0.0191};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (FSS.east) {FSS \hspace{10mm} 2 \hspace{10mm} 0.1084};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (FSF.east) {FSF \hspace{10mm} 1 \hspace{10mm} 0.0191};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (FFS.east) {FFS \hspace{10mm} 1 \hspace{10mm} 0.0191};
    \node[draw=none, anchor=west] at (FFF.east) {FFF \hspace{10mm} 0 \hspace{10mm} 0.0034};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


But I cannot make the labels on the top aligned with the last three columns of the tree.  I even tried this way, but it is hard to add the last three columns of the tree.
Any thought would be greatly appreciated!

Here's a automatic solution with the forest package, an advanced package for typesetting trees.
The pseudo-table is created by setting minimum width for the columns, the headers are placed by naming the SSS node X which will be referenced as the upper most node.
The \fpeval macro evaluates the probabilities while the siunitx package's \num macro is used to typeset the result.
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\forestset{
  credit cards/.style n args={3}{
    before typesetting nodes={
      shape=circle, fill, inner sep=+0pt, minimum size=+3pt,
      for tree={s sep=+2em, grow=0, edge+={line cap=round}, child anchor=west}},
    FS/.style={shape=coordinate},
    S/.style={FS, edge+=blue, edge label={node[midway, inner sep=+.15em, auto=left ]{S}}},
    F/.style={FS, edge+= red, edge label={node[midway, inner sep=+.15em, auto=right]{F}}},
    start/.style={@ccdo={#3}{0}{}{}},
    cc header/.style={yshift=+2em},
    cc header/customer/.style={/forest/cc header, rotate=90, anchor=south west},
    cc header/events/.style  ={/forest/cc header, anchor=south},
    cc header/cust/.style    ={/forest/cc header, align=center, anchor=south, text width=2cm},
    cc header/prob/.style    ={yshift=+2em, anchor=south east, label position=north east},
    cc label/events/.style={minimum width=+3em},
    cc label/cust/.style  ={minimum width=+1em},
    cc label/prob/.style  ={minimum width=+5em},
    cc do header/.style n args={3}{/forest/if={##1}{label={[/forest/cc header/##2]{##3}}}{}},
    @ccdo/.style n args={4}{
      if={##1>0}{
        append/.expanded={[, F, @ccdo={\inteval{##1-1}}{##2}            {##3F}{\unexpanded{##4\*(#1)}}]},
        append/.expanded={[, S, @ccdo={\inteval{##1-1}}{\inteval{##2+1}}{##3S}{\unexpanded{##4\*(#2)}}]},
      }{
        shape=rectangle, anchor=west, content={##3}, cc label/events,
        if={##2==#3}{alias=X}{}, % upper node
        cc do header={##2==#3}{events}{Events},
        label={[%
          anchor=base west, xshift=+10mm, /forest/cc label/cust,
          /forest/cc do header={##2==#3}{cust}{Customers using credit card, $x$},
          label={[anchor=base west, xshift=+10mm, /forest/cc label/prob,
            /forest/cc do header={##2==#3}{prob}{Probabilities}
            ]base east:$\begin{array}[t]{@{}r@{}}\def\*{}##4\\\def\*{*}=\num{\fpeval{1##4}}\end{array}$}
        ]base east:##2}}},
    end draw/.prefix code={%
      \foreach[remember=\nw (initially )]\i in {1, ..., #3}{
        \path[path only] (!r\nw) -- coordinate (@) (!r\nw2)
         node[/forest/cc header/customer] at (@|-X.north) {Customer \i};
        \edef\nw{\nw2}}}}}
\begin{document}
\Forest{credit cards={0.15}{0.85}{3} [, start]}
\end{document}

Output


Thank you very much! I really appreciate your help!
